# AN7323 what does it do?

Tags: integrated-circuit, components

Does anybody know what this chip does? I can't find a datasheet

I think it is a ADC and could use it a lot, if it is. But need a sheet :P

Comment: Some more context on where you heard of it would be good. While there may be some parts with an AN prefix more commonly it stands for 'application note' and after a quick Google I can find any likely examples of either.

Comment: http://www.alldatasheet.net/view.jsp?Searchword=AN7323

Comment: You should attach an image of the actual device where the part number is clearly visible.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure its AN7323 and not AD7323?

> The AD7323
>    is a 4-channel, 12-bit plus sign successive 
>   approximation analog-to-digital converter (ADC)

[datasheet](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD7323.pdf)